# Postman console log not allowing to write string in next line

Tags: javascript, postman, postman-collection-runner

I am trying to display a string on multilines with `\n` in the Postman Console. How can I do this?

Example:

```
var mystr='line\n another line\n another line';
console.log(mystr);
```

Expecting:

```
line
another line
another line
```

Getting:

```
lineanother lineanother line
```

Note: it is working as expected in Firefox scratchpad.

Comment: Try `\\n` instead of `\n`.

Comment: Tried: Result is : line\n another line\n another line

Comment: maybe try '\r\n'

Comment: All of `\n`, `\\n`, `\r\n` do not have any effect in the Postman console.

Answer (score 2):

[Postman console log not allowing to write string in next line #1477](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/issues/1477)

Asked the same question on postman GitHub, I will update here once got the solution.

Thanks, @Danny Dainton :)

Answer (score 2):

type 3 times console.log:

```js
console.log('linea1');
console.log('linea2');
console.log('linea3');
```

Comment: But this creates a new timestamp each time.

Answer (score 2):

You can print multiline text like this:

```
console.log("hello", '\n', "world");
```

Which will show up like this in console:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think that you can achieve this in the Postman console - maybe worth raising an issue on the Postman github project, is there isn’t one already.

I would have suggested doing the same thing as the comments, adding `\n` works in every other console but this one, which is strange.

I think that the only way, at the moment, is just to add multiple `console.log()` statements, to get your vars printing on new lines.

Another alternative is to put what you need into an `array` - This is not ideal but would give you the information in the console, on separate lines.

[image: Postman Console]

Comment: Using the array prints the leading `0: ` line number each time, which prevents copying the printed lines.